# when the page loads, the opacity of a div is appearing, then disappearing and wont come back when sidebar is opened

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to create a pop-out sidebar with a small list of items in it and ive set the opacity to 0 to begin with then when it opens, the opacity is set to 1. Its currently loading, fading in the item, then fading out because of a transition. but im not sure why its fading in to begin with even though i have the opacity set to 0.

```css
.inputItem {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 2vh, 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

```js
function menuOpen() {
  if(!toggled){
    document.getElementsByClassName('inputItem').style = 'opacity: 1;'
    toggled = true
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('inputItem').style = ''
    toggled = false
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='sideMenu' class='sideMenu'>
   <form id='inputWrapper' class=inputWrapper>
      <div id='inputItem' class='inputItem'>
         <input id='x1' type='text' name=''>
         <label class='plntPropInptTxt'>X</label>
         <span></span>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

the full code here: https://orbiting-simulator.erodecode.repl.co
when i remove the item transitions, it doesnt appear then disappear. i believe its loading appeared then because it has a transition, it has to slowly disappear when the opacity code is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like list of elements, not a single element. You'd have to use `for` loop to iterate through list.

An easier solution is to use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead, which simplifies the iteration:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.inputItem').forEach(el => el.style = 'opacity: 1;');
```

But, you should avoid using inline styles, use classes instead.
And instead of controlling opacity of each individual item of the menu, control the menu itself:

```
.sideMenu
{
  opacity: 0;
}
.sideMenu.opened
{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

and javascript:

```
if (toggled)
  sideMenu.classList.remove("opened");
else
  sideMenu.classList.add("opened");
```

Comment: this works for opening it, but it doesnt solve the issue of it appearing/disappearing onload

Comment: Try removing this part just to troubleshoot and see if the disappearing issue... disappears.
`
else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('inputItem').style = ''
    toggled = false
  }
`